# Why C and B are the correct answers? Is the bold part a conditional type?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conditionals

While small amounts of other minerals ---1--- the savory hill, **the salt pile would have a near translucent quality if not for the thin layer of reddish clay ---2--- the exterior.**

1. A. pervades B. is pervading **C.** pervade D. has pervaded
2. A. has coated **B.** coating C. been coated D. coat

Answer (score 1):

1. "pervade" is correct as "small amounts" (plural) is the subject. i.e. if it was "small amounts of a mineral" it would still be "pervade" not "pervades". "Have pervaded" would not be incorrect, but with a slightly different meaning (the pervasion was in the past).
2. "coating" is correct. This is a (normally) simplified form of "that is coating". "That coats" would also works, and in this case the "that" is not optional. "Layer" (singular) is the subject.